# youtube player api, conflict with other javascript eg twitter like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, youtube

This code works fine for the youtube iframe api player method.  But if I navigate to a page, then click back to the original page, the player does not load.  This only happens when I have the javascript code for twitter included.  If I take out the twitter js, it works fine, obviously I'd like a twitter like button.  Also this happens with sumome button.

Wonder anyone has any ideas or has found a solution to this problem.  Thanks.

**youtube code**

```
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('youplayer',
  {
      height: '250',
      width: '290',
      events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
  });
}

// load player with first video                
function onPlayerReady() {
  var value1 = $('#1stvideoid').val();
  player.cueVideoById(value1);
}
```

**twitter js code**

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

Comment: are you getting a console error?

Comment: no errors. looking at inspector

Comment: There appears no conflicts with variable names, is this the all code?